# insert into select where destination table has extra auto-increment column

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a silly little problem. I have a large table with hundreds of columns, so I don't want to write out each column name individually. The problem is that say, `table1` is the source table, with 200 columns, and `table2` is the destination table with 201 columns, where the last column of `table2` is an extra auto-increment (primary key) column. The idea is that I simply can do

`insert into table2 select * from table1 where row = ##;`

and I would wish that all the data would be copied and the auto-increment column would just do its job. However I get this pesky error message:

> Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Anyone have a simple solution to this?

Comment: *I don't want to write out each column name individually.* MUST has priority over WANT.

Comment: The answer is to just give a NULL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493612/how-to-insert-new-row-to-database-with-auto-increment-column-without-specifying

Comment: *The answer is to just give a NULL* MySQL does not allow `SELECT NULL, * FROM ..`, only `SELECT *, NULL FROM ..`. If "an extra auto-increment (primary key) column" is the last column in `table2`'s structure then this is a solution.

Comment: @Akina ok I didn't notice that. I luckily am working with the case using `*, NULL` and it is working.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to generate the column names with a SQL query and just cut-and-paste.

But you can also use the temporary table approach:

```
create table temp_table1 as
    select * from table1 where row = ##;

alter table temp_table1 drop column row;
```

Then you can use `temp_table1` with `*`.  Of course, this assumes that all the other columns line up!  I also recommend listing all the columns for the `insert` . . . and you are back to the recommendation at the beginning of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution can be create a backup of the table2, drop the autoincrement column  then insert whatever to you want to insert as the column number would match, and then you can add the autoincrement column at the end again.